# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order' - Order is column name

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, winforms

I keep getting the following exception:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order'.
```

I have a TABLE with columns: `Name`, `Credits`, `Extension`, `Order`. `Order` is of type `bigint`. Now when I go to `INSERT` a single record into this table, it gives me the above exception.

I have put it in a try/catch block and caught the exception, I have set breakpoints and it does not reveal anything *other than* the above message.

Can anybody please help shed some light on this? I'm sitting here, scratching my head wondering what the heck is going on and I just can't figure it out. I don't see where I've gone wrong.

```
        try
        {
            // Insert into database
            sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=sblah blah blah... intentionally  removed;");

            sqlconnection.Open();

            using (var command = new SqlCommand("Insert Into Images(Name, Credits, Extension, Order) VALUES (@Name, @Credits, @Extension, @Order)", sqlconnection))
            {
                command.CommandTimeout = 240;

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", workingPicture.Properties.Filename);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Credits", workingPicture.Properties.Credits);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Extension", workingPicture.Properties.Extension);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Order", workingPicture.Properties.Order);

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                doneUpdatingDB = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
            doneUpdatingDB = false;
        }
```

The value of `Order` is `0`.

Comment: `Order` is a SQL keyword. Your column with the same name needs to be wrapped in square brackets, like this `[Order]`

Comment: The right thing to do is to not use reserved words for identifiers.  Change the column name to something like `ordering` or `priority` or `OrderId` or something else non-reserved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order is the keyword in the SQL, Change the name of the field in the DB or make [] around the order keyword like "[order]"

Comment: Oh thank you, I can't believe how bad my memory gets when I don't do certain things for a long time.

Answer (score 8):

`ORDER` is a [reserved keyword](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in SQL Server. You have to enclose is in square brackets if you want to use it as a column name:

```
"Insert Into Images(Name, Credits, Extension, [Order]) VALUES (@Name, @Credits, @Extension, @Order)"
```

It is best to avoid using reserved keywords to name your objects (tables, columns, stored procs, etc.).